# Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud Phone number formatting

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

If Sales Cloud is set to accept 10 digit phone numbers and marketing cloud requires an 11 digit phone number (incl. 1) in the US.

What is the fix for making sure your journey gets the data in the correct format so that the SMS can send properly?

Am I missing something? Wouldn't you think the two systems are compatible OOTB?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this article: '[SMS will not send to a new contact in a Journey with a Salesforce Entry Event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318131&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)'

> To stop the normalization process within Salesforce, you can format the phone number in Salesforce as +[country code][phone number].

Comment: Thank you.  Send it to IT to see what they can do.  Not sure why it was not set up this way.